# javascript closures: how they start leaking memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

many programmers believe javascript closures starts leaking memory.

I want to see some examples where this happens.

I dont want to see closure being added as events to dom elements and removing dom elements in IE. As in link below

```
function foo(value) {   
    var bar = document.getElementById("selector");
    bar.attachEvent("onclick", 
        // closure
        function() {
            alert(value);  
        }
    ); 
}
```

i want to see some other cases where closures may start to leak.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up on jAndy's link (for the full picture still follow the link).

Closures them selfs are not a big problem, the problems comes when you don't understand that the everything in the inherited scopes continues to live on as long as the closure exists.

#### Example

```
function doAmazingGrace() {

    // gigantic list of stuff!
    var list = [...]; 
    var result = magicComputationOnTheList();

    // readOnlyResults for whatever reason....
    return {
        get: function() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

`result` itself is not a problem since it has to live on in order for the closure to work, but `list` will be "leaked", unless you loose the reference to the closure it will go away so it's not technically a leak.

But as long as the closure lives on, you keep a reference to `list` in there, which isn't needed.

So in order to fix it, it would be wise to use `delete list` or `list = null` before returning the object, so that the Array can be garbage collected.

The second issue are circular references, but that's not a closure issue, you can always introduce circular references and whether and how long they leak is also dependent on the garbage collectors ability to get rid of them. V8 does a good job at that, old IE versions had extreme problems with it though.